# Storing an Enum type in an unboxed Vector

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have something like this:

```
data Colour = Red | Blue | Green
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded, Read, Show)
```

And I want to have an unboxed `Vector` of `Colour`s. I obviously cannot do this directly (because `Colour` isn't an instance of `Unbox`), but I also can't tell how I would write the `Unbox` instance for `Colour`. The the documentation for `Unbox` doesn't seem to say how you make something an instance of it (or at least, not in a way I understand).

Comment: Taking a brief glance at the docs, it looks like `Unbox` doesn’t actually have any methods—you should be able to just define `instance Unbox Colour` as long as you have also defined `instance Data.Vector.Generic.Vector Vector Colour` and `instance Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.MVector MVector Colour`.

Comment: @AlexisKing Those instances are what confuse me. What on earth is ``Data.Vector.Generic.Vector Vector`` exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to use [`Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-th-unbox-0.2.1.2/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Deriving.html), which uses template Haskell to define the correct instances for the new types in terms of existing types with `Unbox` instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, TemplateHaskell #-}
module Enum where


import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Data.Vector.Generic.Base
import Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving
import Data.Word



data Colour = Red | Blue | Green
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded, Read, Show)

colourToWord8 :: Colour -> Word8
colourToWord8 c =
    case c of
      Red -> 0
      Blue -> 1
      Green -> 2

word8ToColour :: Word8 -> Colour
word8ToColour w =
    case w of
      0 -> Red
      1 -> Blue
      _ -> Green


derivingUnbox "Colour"
  [t| Colour -> Word8 |]
  [| colourToWord8 |]
  [| word8ToColour |]


test n = U.generate n (word8ToColour . fromIntegral . (`mod` 3))
```

Of course this wastes space in this case because we only use 2 of the 8 bits in `Word8`.